# Not able to post json value from angularjs to php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I have written a service in angular to post values to PHP page. It looks something like this:

```
postValues: function(id,userImg) {
               return $http({ 
                      method: 'post',
                      url: 'phppage.php',
                      data: { id: 1,number: 3 },
                      dataType: 'json',
                      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                });
        }
```

and my PHP code looks something like this.

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$no=$_POST['number'];
```

But I get undefined index error.

Then I tried another way:

```
$postdata       = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request        = json_decode($postdata);
$id             = $request->id;
$number         = $request->number;
```

But this also doesn't yield any results.

What could be the possible reason? Isn't this the right way to POST values from angular to PHP.

P.S: I also tried using jQuery's $.param().

Comment: `$http` is called in the wrong way, read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: It's not wrong. This is specified inside a factory. And it worked for me for other services where header is different. @k102

Comment: Have you tried logging the response to the console to isolate the issue as to whether the problem occurs in Angular vs PHP?

Comment: Change your headers from headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} to headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

Answer (score 0):

try to send http request like this and use promise to catch the response inside ur factory function

```
 postValues: function(id,userImg){
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'phppage.php',
          data: { id: 1,number: 3 },
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).then(function(response){
          return response
        },function(response){
           return response
        })
    }
```